Getting image URL using Contentful for React App
I'm trying to access the image I have stored on contentful cms but I can't find the url I need, I can access other data like 'title', 'description', 'company' but I can not see how to access images from contentful cms.
This is what my data structure looks like
{title: 'Winning Team', company: 'Pow Pow', description: 'bkbb  dfkwndf enfdiwoen fenwdinewd ewndinqw dn qn dwned', image: {…}}
company
: 
"Pow Pow"
description
: 
"bkbb  dfkwndf enfdiwoen fenwdinewd ewndinqw dn qn dwned"
image
: 
sys
: 
{type: 'Link', linkType: 'Asset', id: '10jOjKpdT197KlAs'}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
title
: 
"Winning Team"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

I tried using product.fields.image.sys.id as my url but it did not work.
I tried using client.getEntries but it returned back an empty array to me
  const client = createClient({
        accessToken: 's-u8l28',
        space: 'zpu6hd',
    })
    // getting a specific Post
    client
        .getEntries({ 'sys.id': '10jO7KlAs' })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))

{sys: {…}, total: 0, skip: 0, limit: 100, items: Array(0), …}
items
: 
[]
limit
: 
100
skip
: 
0
sys
: 
{type: 'Array'}
total
: 
0
stringifySafe
: 
ƒ (serializer = null, indent = "")

Full Product Page code below
import { Link, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"
import { createClient } from 'contentful'


const ProductsGrid = () => {

    const client = createClient({
        accessToken: 's4Hl',
        space: 'zpu5y6hd',
    })
    // getting a specific Post
    client
        .getEntries({ 'sys.id': '10jOjKAs' })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))


    const { products } = useLoaderData();
    return (
        <div className='pt-12 grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 '>
            {products.map((product) => {
                const { title, description, image } = product.fields;
                const id = image.sys.id
                return (
                    <Link
                        key={product.title}
                        to={`/products/${product.id}`}
                        className='card w-full  shadow-xl hover:shadow-2xl transition duration-300 '
                    >
                        <figure className='px-4 pt-4'>
                            <img
                                src={id}
                                alt={title}
                                className='rounded-xl h-64 md:h-48 w-full object-cover'
                            />
                        </figure>
                        <div className='card-body items-center text-center'>
                            <h2 className='card-title capitalize tracking-wider'>{title}</h2>

                        </div>
                    </Link>

                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
export default ProductsGrid;

